# Split data into continuous groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am fairly new to coding so please bear with me. I have a pandas df with either a continuous sequence of positive or negative values or 0.

```
    df = 
    x    y
0   -5   25
1   -7   32
2   -3   33
3    0   22
4    1   16
5    6   10
6    3   36
7    0   22
8    0   55
9   -10  24
10  -9   32 
11  -8   5
12  11   4
13  17   9
14  13   88
15   0   14
16   0   12
17   0   0
18   0   10
19   0   96
20  -1   492
21  -9   -440
22  -3   34
```

I want to break up this data like so:

```
data1 = [-5 -7 -3 0]
data2 = [1 6 3 0 0]
data3 = [-10 -9 -8]
data4 = [11 17 13 0 0 0 0 0]
data5 = [-1 -9 -3]
```

Where value 0 or any number of 0's together are placed with the values that preceded it and into sets that are negative or positive only.

Any help or pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: First of all.  Your `df` is a `list` not a dataframe.  What does the actual dataframe look like?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have changed it to reflect the actual data frame.

Comment: That is better.  You are still missing a good description of how you expect the results to be presented.  As stated, it appears you want a dynamic way to present an arbitrary number of results.  The best way to handle that is in a dictionary.  You could also put the information in the same dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

I treat it as `pandas` `Series`

```
#A=pd.Series(lst)
idx=A.index
A=A.loc[A!=0].to_frame('Val')
A['Group']=A.ge(0).astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
A=A.reindex(idx)
A.Val=A.Val.fillna(0).astype(int)
A.Group=A.Group.ffill()
A.groupby('Group').Val.apply(list).tolist()


[[-5, -7, -3, 0],
 [1, 6, 3, 0, 0],
 [-10, -9, -8],
 [11, 17, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [-1, -9, -3]]
```

About the dataframe A

```
A
Out[23]: 
    Val  Group
0    -5    1.0
1    -7    1.0
2    -3    1.0
3     0    1.0
4     1    2.0
5     6    2.0
6     3    2.0
7     0    2.0
8     0    2.0
9   -10    3.0
10   -9    3.0
11   -8    3.0
12   11    4.0
13   17    4.0
14   13    4.0
15    0    4.0
16    0    4.0
17    0    4.0
18    0    4.0
19    0    4.0
20   -1    5.0
21   -9    5.0
22   -3    5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

### `np.split` and `np.flatnonzero`

The point here is to create a boolean array that identifies where the value changes among being negative, positive, or zero while also not being zero.  This will find the beginnings of groups.

```
a = np.sign(df.x.values)
b = np.append(False, a[:-1] != a[1:])
splits_dict = dict(enumerate(np.split(df, np.flatnonzero(a.astype(bool) & b))))

pd.concat(splits_dict)

       x    y
0 0   -5   25
  1   -7   32
  2   -3   33
  3    0   22
1 4    1   16
  5    6   10
  6    3   36
  7    0   22
  8    0   55
2 9  -10   24
  10  -9   32
  11  -8    5
3 12  11    4
  13  17    9
  14  13   88
  15   0   14
  16   0   12
  17   0    0
  18   0   10
  19   0   96
4 20  -1  492
  21  -9 -440
  22  -3   34
```

---

## `set_index`

If the intention is to embed the information back into the dataframe, we could have just done:

```
a = np.sign(df.x.values)
b = np.append(False, a[:-1] != a[1:])
c = (a.astype(bool) & b).cumsum()

df.set_index([c, df.index])

       x    y
0 0   -5   25
  1   -7   32
  2   -3   33
  3    0   22
1 4    1   16
  5    6   10
  6    3   36
  7    0   22
  8    0   55
2 9  -10   24
  10  -9   32
  11  -8    5
3 12  11    4
  13  17    9
  14  13   88
  15   0   14
  16   0   12
  17   0    0
  18   0   10
  19   0   96
4 20  -1  492
  21  -9 -440
  22  -3   34
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without directly assigning data1, data2 etc? as I will most likely have thousands.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. I will study this and figure out how this works.To answer your other question about how the present the data, I would also like to keep the corresponding Y values. I will frame any subsequent questions more clearly. I appreciate your help